# NodeJS+MongoDB Query Returns Full Results Despite Of Exclusions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a query set up to return all customers except their ids as the following:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.collection("customers").find({}, { _id: 0, name: 1, address: 1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

But it was still returning the full result with _ids, like this:

```
➜  tests node filter.js
[ { _id: 5a68801ec0dbfd8b5d38dc13,
    name: 'John',
    address: 'Highway 71' },...]
```

I was following this example on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp). My Node.JS is 8.94, NPM 5.6.0, and MongoDB 3.0.1.

What did I do wrong?

P.S: Also, even if I change `name:1` to `name:0` to create a `mix of inclusion and exclusion` error, it will not prompt and returns full result!

Comment: Have you tried putting single or double quotation marks around the `_id` key when you try to exclude it? I.e. `{ '_id': 0, ... }`

Comment: Still not working. I downloaded mongodb from `npm`

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
 dbo.collection("customers").find({}, { _id: 0 }, function (err, docs) {     
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(docs);
     db.close();          
     });
});
```

Comment: A cursor was returned with your function like this `Cursor {
  pool: null,
  ...}
`

Comment: Not really. What version of mongodb are you using? It is stilling printing a cursor `Cursor {
  pool: null,...}`